# Is there any health/fitness band or activity tracker which supports alarms or vibration from third party apps?

Tags: jawbone, mapmyfitness

Hi I am developing an android app which needs to send alert to the fitness device worn by the user.Basically it should make the band vibrate or sound an alarm.

I checked many bands including mapmyrun,jawbone etc but they are not exposing this api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that Fitbit gives this feature for some of their bands

https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/devices/#alarms

"Fitbit activity trackers (excluding MobileTrack) have the ability to set alarms.
Get Alarms
Resource URL
GET https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/devices/tracker/[tracker-id]/alarms.json"

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [GoogleFit](https://developers.google.com/fit/)? It is supposed to be integrated with all of them, so you can use a Vivofit, Fitbit or the one you want. Not sure if this is the correct answer, but for sure it will give you some clues about it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx , but I am looking for a band to which my application can send an alarm and it should vibrate.

Answer (score -1):

Some watches from bpdoctormed have a silent vibration function
https://bpdoctormed.com/collections/all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).